Node.js v20 global fetch not returning cookies
This endpoint sets a cookie, then redirects to a list of cookies:
https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/king/cole
When I go there in a browser, I get the expected result:
{
  "cookies": {
    "king": "cole"
  }
}

I get the same result when in the browser's console:
const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/king/cole')
await res.json()
// -> { cookies: { king:cole }}

But, if I execute those lines in Node, I get an empty set:
// Welcome to Node.js v20.12.0.
// Type ".help" for more information.
const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/king/cole')
await res.json()
// -> { cookies: {} }

Adding credentials: 'include' to the fetch doesn't help (and shouldn't be necessary?)
How can I get this to work?

Nodejs does not, by default, maintain cookies for you.  You have to do that manually.
So, you send the first request: https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/king/cole and get the cookie back in the response, but then when it redirects to https://httpbin.org/cookies, nodejs does not send the previous cookies back to the server on that redirect.  Therefore, the server gets the redirect request with no cookies on it and that's what it shows you.
For node-fetch, there are NPM modules that will act as a cookie jar and manage cookies for you (similar to what the browser does). On first glance, I don't see anything in NPM for the fetch() interface, but I'd be surprised if someone hasn't implemented it somewhere.

Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Do you have any primary sources indicating that is what's happening?  The Node docs simply say "A browser-compatible implementation of the fetch() function." and links to MDN, whose version notably does support cookies natively.  If we have to manage our own cookies, it means we have to (at minimum) also manage redirects .

@MonkeyBoson - I do not have a good reference for it.  It's a hard thing to search on because all the search hits seem to refer to node-fetch which is a 3rd party fetch-like implementation.  I based this answer on two pieces of info.  One, it fits your results.  Two, other ways of making an http request in nodejs do not manage cookies for you at all unless you hook them up to a cookiejar type of object that can persist cookies.

@MonkeyBoson - I did find this reference which just says that cookie handling with fetch in nodejs is "complex" and you may get unexpected outcomes in a Node.js environment. No detail on what that actually means.  The Nodejs site itself offers no documentation on the fetch() interface - simply referring you to MDN.

@monkeyboson - Hard to tell for sure, but this function httpRedirectFetch() appears to specifically clear cookies before making the request.  See nodejs code here.

I found the same thing.  I suppose it's my own fault for relying on an extremely complex function that has one line of documentation.  I've found this wrapper for global fetch (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-cookie) but it has its own downsides due to the limitations of the current implementation of fetch.

According to this, the Node implementation is based on undici, which does seem to handle cookies.  Clearly, though, it doesn't.  Does that mean that one day global fetch will?  Nobody knows.

@MonkeyBoson - Why not just use node-fetch or one of the other http libraries (I tend to use got()) and then one of the cookie jar libraries that goes with those.  I don't even like the fetch() programming interface with an extra line of code just to read the response, much less the fact that there's zero doc for nodejs.

Thank you for the recommendation.  I've used got before, and request before that.  The first line of the got docs right now is "use ky, which is based on fetch".  I was hoping with a client built into core, there would finally be some stability.

@MonkeyBoson - got() is still there and still being maintained.  I don't consider "based on fetch() to be a benefit for anything other than code size which is inconsequential to me for a nodejs app.
